# Read from Firebase into Table View

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to display my "messages" in a table view, for some reason it isn't showing up, tried everything and cannot see my issue.

Any help is appreciated.

```
class StatusViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var dataView: UITableView!

var array = [String]()

var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view:

    // Setting firebase database reference:
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    // Retrieve the users
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("message").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let item = snapshot.value as? String{
            self.array.append(item)
            self.dataView.reloadData()
        }

    })

    self.dataView.delegate = self
    self.dataView.dataSource = self

}

// "$uid === auth.uid"

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = dataView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}

// Back To App View Controller:
@IBAction func BackToStatus(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToStatus", sender: nil)
}
```

}

Database Rules

[image]

Users and Messages I am trying to display

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting an error? Can you print snapshot.value? Can you confirm the query is returning data?

Comment: Getting a permissions error, but do not see why this is the case?

Comment: @gavfoley7 if you get an error that you could not read the data, why would you think that has nothing to do with putting the data in the tableview?

Comment: Please post the error